# How to change tag info for all documents in R?

Tags: r

I just started learning R and here is a question:

I have a Corpus with 20 documents:

```
> length(crude)
[1] 20
```

each document has the following tags:

```
> meta(crude[[2]])
  author       : BY TED D'AFFLISIO, Reuters
  datetimestamp: 1987-02-26 17:34:11
  description  : 
  heading      : OPEC MAY HAVE TO MEET TO FIRM PRICES - ANALYSTS
  id           : 144
  language     : en
  origin       : Reuters-21578 XML
  topics       : YES
  lewissplit   : TRAIN
  cgisplit     : TRAINING-SET
  oldid        : 5687
  places       : usa
  people       : character(0)
  orgs         : opec
  exchanges    : character(0)
```

If I need to modify any tag, I can do the following:

```
DublinCore(crude[[1]], tag = "creator") <- "John Doe"
```

My question is how do I apply the change to all 20 documents? I thought

```
DublinCore(crude[[1:20]], tag = "creator") <- "John Doe"
```

Apparently it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using single brackets instead of double brackets. For lists, double brackets are used to select one element of the list (which is why it works when you modify one specific tag). A single bracket returns a list of the selected elements.

```
DublinCore(crude[1:20], tag = "creator") <- "John Doe"
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the [1:20], it prompts: `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`